# How to add double quotes in a list of list Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I ran into a problem.

Got a dataset as such:

```
dataset = [['9874, 209384, 20938'], ['9874,209384, 20938'], ['9874, 209384, 20938']]
```

Initially wanted to run Apriori on it but the problem is that the individual item in the list of list is not in quotation mark.

Desired output:

```
dataset = [['9874', '209384', '20938'], ['9874', '209384', '20938'], ['9874', '209384', '20938']]
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I can see, each list of lists i.e. ['9874, 209384, 20938'] has a string inside this list. Means the whole value '9874, 209384, 20938' is a string.
So, you can try this:

```
dataset = [['9874, 209384, 20938'], ['9874,209384, 20938'], ['9874, 209384, 20938']]
 """ Create an empty list"""
emp_list = []

for i in range(len(dataset)):
   emp_list.append(dataset[i][0].split()
```

What I did was took strings of each list, and split them and append it to the empty list.
Now your dataset would look like this:

emp_list = [['9874,', '209384,', '20938'], ['9874,209384,', '20938'], ['9874,', '209384,', '20938']].

Hope thos helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function.

```
x =[['9874, 209384, 20938'], ['9874,209384, 20938'], ['9874, 209384, 20938']]

x = [i[0].split(",") for i in x]
print(x)

// [['9874', ' 209384', ' 20938'], ['9874', '209384', ' 20938'], ['9874', ' 209384', ' 20938']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
   res =  [ i[0].split(", ") for i in dataset]
```

---

**res:**

```
[['9874', '209384', '20938'],
 ['9874,209384', '20938'],
 ['9874', '209384', '20938']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your example has inconsistent spacing, this will be more tolerant:

```py
>>> [[y.strip() for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in dataset]
[['9874', '209384', '20938'], ['9874', '209384', '20938'], ['9874', '209384', '20938']]
```

Comment: you can use more than one character in your split string: `.split(', ')` that way you don't need to call `.strip()`.

Comment: Sure, but in the example, not all of the commas have a space after them, which not work with `.split(', ')`

Comment: oh. you're right. good catch. Looks like the other posters are missing that detail as well.